# Is this possible to do using excel and the index?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image]

Next to each name, I would like the time and date they picked. So TK would be 03/29/17 09:30 am.

I tried to use
`=INDEX($C$4:$BM$4,MATCH("OK",C5:BK5,0))`

But with that I can only get the time. If I add the date to the time (03/29/17 09:00 and 03/29/17 09:30) and then try to copy to other times, it converts 1:30pm to 10:30am.

What can I do to have the time and date they picked next to their name?!

Comment: Use custom format `mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM` for date with time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Format the Time cells C3:BM3 (like the picture) Custom `mm/dd/yy hh:mm AM/PM` and write the date with the time (you will need to change the column width), also format the empty column (where you write the formula) with the same custom format

`=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$BM$3,MATCH("OK",C4:BM4,0)),"")`

Write the above formula next to TK in B4 the new column (Blank) and you can drag it down
If no OK in the row next to the name it will return empty ""
C4:BM4 is all the columns under date, It will change when you drag it down with the reference corresponding to each name

Comment: So for each date I need to write in the date myself?

Comment: You can use a formula `=D2&" "&TEXT(C3,"hh:mm AM/PM")` in a new row, then copy paste special values in the needed place `Wed 29 10:00 AM` it is how it looks